# Атомарные функции unix

Tags: c, unix

Всем добрый день!
Подскажите плиз, есть ли в unix-подобных системах возможность создать свою функцию, которая выполнялась бы атомарно (так, чтобы планировщик не передавал управление никаким другим потокам, пока не завершит ее выполнение) ?

Comment: IMHO нет. Используйте sigprocmask() и мьютексы или семафоры.

Comment: @avp, sigprocmask() разве может помешать передать управление другому потоку?

Comment: Если речь идет о пользовательском пространстве - ответ однозначный: нельзя, используйте блокировку для защиты разделяемых данных (например, мьютексы).

Если речь идет о пространстве ядра - советую познакомиться с `preempt_disable()` / `preempt_enable()` и... никогда не использовать ;)

Comment: @northerner, вопрос о пользовательском пространстве, но как таковой защиты данных в данном случае не требуется,- хочется чтобы при получении сигнала завершения обработчик не прерывался и не передавал управление другим потокам, и не хочется растягивать обработчик и посылать им pthread_cancel(). Может еще способы есть красиво выйти при завершении, чтобы остальные потоки не пытались читать уже несуществующие данные?

Comment: @margosh, sigprocmask() помогает только блокировать прерывание. Если в "заблокированной" секции истечет квант времени планировщика или будет сделан системный вызов, то конечно, поток может быть переключен. 

А в многопроцессорной системе у Вас все равно одновременно (физически одновременно) будут исполняться несколько потоков. Так что общие данные (для многопоточной программы) надо в любом случае защищать мьютексами (семафорами).

sigprocmask() просто помогает исключить возможное влияние обработчика сигнала на участок кода потока.

--

А что Вы называете **"обработчик"** в своем комментарии ?

Comment: @avp, Функцию, которую регистрирую в sigaction()

Comment: @margosh, извините, но если Вы допускаете *"и посылать им pthread_cancel()"*, то это какое-то недопонимание ситуации. 

Обработчик сигнала (именно его регистрируют в sigaction()) не следует связывать с определенным потоком. Конечно, при определенных усилиях, можно добиться, чтобы некий сигнал обрабатывался только в конкретном потоке, **но зачем ???**. 

Более того, ни одну из функций связанных с posix threads из этого обработчика **вызывать нельзя**. IMHO из механизмов синхронизации в нем доступен только sem\_post() (ну, не считая kill(), write()...).
См. man 7 signal. Там есть список функций

Comment: В википедии в статье Critial section есть пример для pthread (с мьютексами) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_section

Comment: @avp, Вы правы, pthread_cancel() использовать нельзя. Я зря на планировщике зациклилась, атомарность функции на многопроцессорной системе меня не спасет. В таком случае, не подскажите, как обычно реализуется обработчик SIGTERM в многопоточной программе? Получается, что большую часть ресурсов я освободить в нем не могу...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[@margosh](/users/6966/margosh), лично я обычно во всех обработчиках всех сигналов просто выставляю флаг (в volatile int переменной). (В тестовом режиме не боюсь вызывать printf()).

Если обработчик сигнала и функции, которые этот сигнал интересует, хорошо локализуются по смыслу задачи, то я пишу их в одном файле и флаг объявляю static, иначе делаю флаг extern.

**Безусловно**, проверка флага с целью выполнения каких-то действий и затем его сброса должна быть защищена мьютексом (от потоков) и sigprocmask() (от сигнала).

Видимо у Вас, при такой схеме, один из потоков (планировщик) должен иметь маску сигналов, разрешающую SIGTERM, а **все остальные** маску с **заблокированным**  SIGTERM. В таком случае прерывание ожидания (read(), select(), sigpause(), sleep() и т.п.) после обработки сигнала произойдет именно в *нужном*, а не в произвольном потоке.
Иначе планировщик может никогда изменения флага не увидеть.

Другое решение состоит в записи (системным вызовом write()) обработчиком сигнала в pipe некоторой "команды". В дальнейшем какой-то поток (в Вашем случае планировщик) может прочесть ее и выполнить необходимые действия.

IMHO что-то в таком духе (по крайней мере в Linux).

Вообще же, очень часто, достаточно SIGTERM просто не ловить т.к. на самом деле никакие реально нужные ресурсы не пропадают. Вы просто для себя рассмотрите случай с SIGKILL в произвольный момент - катастрофа произойдет ?

Отловить завершение и зафиксировать в логах можно враппером.

Comment: @avp, Спасибо за подробный ответ, подумаю, что лучше подойдет!